# How do I change the following pattern to find all possible matches?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a Java pattern here

```
    String patternString = "(#)(.+?)([\\s,#.])";
```

I basically want to find all words beginning with a '#' in a given text string. The pattern matches all words except the last one if it is followed by an end line. I am using a hash map to store the values.

```
    int x = 0;

    HashMap<Integer, String> values = new HashMap<>();

    while(matcher.find()) {
        values.put(x++, matcher.group(2));
    }
```

I have tried putting a '$' symbol in the third to match the group but it doesn't seem to work. How do I tweak the pattern to match all words beginning with a '#' that includes the last word too?

Comment: Consider `\b` (word boundary) instead of `\s`, or alternate with `$` end of string anchor

Comment: Use `String patternString = "#(\\w+)";` and grab `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your requirements, it can be much simpler. I'd suggest using the following pattern:

```
(#)([^\s]+)
```

It matches a # followed by as many non-white space characters as possible. You'll have to change you code to use group 1 instead of group 2, as my pattern doesn't have 3 groups.

Depending on your exact requirements you can also use `\w` instead of `[^\s]` to match any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]).

Comment: Actually I needed the word immediately after the #, so I just continued using group 2. The solution works to suit my need however, with a few minor modifications. Thanks!